# Jquery ajax not getting json response from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, email

Everything was working right using the same logic, but with PHP mail(). Now that I replaced it with PHPMailer I'm not getting the json response when the script sends the email.

Javascript code:

```
        $("#forma_contacto").submit(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "contact.php",
            data: $("#forma_contacto").serialize()
        }).done(function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
            $(".resultado-contacto").html(respuesta.mensaje);
            if(respuesta.resultado == 'enviado'){
                $(".contact-form-area")[0].reset();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$sendTo = "xxx@xxxxxx.com";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

$respuesta = array('resultado' => FALSE);

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if($city != '')
{
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>No se permiten bots</div>";
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    exit(); 
}
if ($name == "")
{
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Por favor dinos tu nombre</div>";
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    exit();
}
if ($email == "")
{
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Es necesario tu correo electrónico</div>"; 
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    exit();
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>El correo es inválido</div>";
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    exit();
}
if ($message == "")
{
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Por favor escribe tu mensaje</div>";
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    exit();
}
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
{
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Solo se permiten letras y espacios para tu nombre</div>";
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    exit();
}

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->isSMTP();                      
    $mail->Host       = 'xxx.xxxx.xxx';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;        
    $mail->Username   = '**************';
    $mail->Password   = '*************';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port       = 587;                           

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($sendTo);
    $mail->addAddress($sendTo);
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = $message;

    if($mail->send())
    {
        $respuesta['mensaje'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Mensaje enviado exitósamente.</div>";    
        $respuesta['resultado'] = 'enviado';        
    } else {
        $respuesta['mensaje'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Ocurrió un error y el mensaje no fué enviado. Intena nuevamente.</div>";
        $respuesta['resultado'] = 'error';      
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Ocurrió un error y el mensaje no fué enviado.</div>";
    $respuesta['resultado'] = $mail->ErrorInfo;
    error_log($mail->ErrorInfo);
} finally {
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    exit();
}
```

If I run a test not passing form validations on purpose I get all the json responses alright. But not when the email is sent correctly. I get nothing on the javascript side.

Any ideas? I'm pretty sure it's going to be something simple, but my mind goes no more.

Comment: Is the request returning data? Check the network tab to see what is being returned. Check the server logs are showing any php script errors to see if the script is erroring out and thus not providing an output

Comment: Email is being sent, no PHP errors and I have used error_log() for testing inside 'finally' and it does logged it, so PHP script executes completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh well. It's working now. I made so many tests that I lost track of what the solution really was.

However, my main suspicion is the DEBUG feature of PHPMailer was on and it "polluted" the 'echo' (json) when email was sent. So, I turned it off.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF
```